# How do I only stylize parts of my tellraw command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I make only the channel text blue, not the hashtag?

```
/tellraw @a {"text":"#            channel          #","clickEvent":{"action":"open_url","value":"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCI4ELo3t9YqaSwP3aqxY2Xw?view_as=subscriber"},"color":"blue","bold":true}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
/tellraw @a [{"text":"#","bold":"true"},{"text":" channel ","color":"blue","bold":"true"},{"text":"#","bold":"true"}]
```

You can find information about /tellraw and some examples on the wiki: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/tellraw